# How to combine string time with datetime date in aws lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I'm getting input from user that is a string - `"9 am"`, `"10 pm"`, etc. 
I want to append that today's date.

```
from datetime import date

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    today = date.today()
    print("Today's date:", today)

    starttime = "9"
    ampm = "am"
    timestring = starttime+":00 "+ampm
    fulldt = today+" "+timestring
```

This results in `"errorMessage": "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.date' and 'str'"`

I'm also trying `dateime.datetime.combine(today, timestring)` and that also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't combine `str` and `date` objets, one way is to do

```
fulldt = str(today) + " " + timestring
```

converting the date object into str

Answer (score 1):

@Reznik has it right, although, for bonus points, use Python's new [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) whenever you can:

`fulldt = f'{today} {timestring}'`